# how to override onMessage method in firebase cloud messaging?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I get the notification and method in `FirebaseMessaging` that the `onMessage` is triggered, I see the data, but since they first pass through the native code, when I minimize the application and try to send a message, it immediately appears, I need to do that in some cases if I passed some parameter of the `bool` type, I did not show them.

Between this, when the application is open, I don’t see any notifications at all, but the `onMessage` method works. I can try to get the data in `onMessage` and then show the local notification using `flutter_local_notifications`, but then this method will not work on ios since local notifications are not allowed.

The question is, how can I first get the data from the notification, and after parsing the data from the notification, in some cases, can I show the notification? I do not see a way out how to do this natively?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to utilise the native plugin for Firebase Messaging and then handle the logic in `onMessageReceived` ([Android documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)). Then you can force your app to always show notifications if you build the notification yourself. An [article](https://medium.com/@cdmunoz/working-easily-with-fcm-push-notifications-in-android-e1804c80f74) has been posted about on Medium it as well. I do not know if you need the same behaviour for iOS or if it acts as intended now?

Comment: behavior on ios be the same

Comment: I found something like this https://wajahatkarim.com/2018/05/firebase-notifications-in-background--foreground-in-android/, but I think I will write my own library